# How would requirejs be used to modularize this snippet?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to wrap my head around modular front-end development, and trying to modularize some simple code as an exercise. I've read about requirejs and browserify, but I don't really fully understand yet if and how it would apply to what I'm trying to accomplish (it seems to be geared more towards nodejs and app development).

To keep it simple, let's say I have the following google analytics snippet from the html5 boilerplate:

```
/* Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. */
(function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
e.src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X');ga('send','pageview');
```

What I'd like to do is replace the `'UA-XXXXX-X'` string with a variable, that can be declared when someone wants to use the analytics snippet. A bit like the following pseudo code:

main.js:

```
var myGoogleId = 'UA-12345-0';
```

analytics-module.js

```
/* Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. */
(function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
e.src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
ga('create',myGoogleId);ga('send','pageview');
```

index.html

```
<html>
  ...
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/analytics-module.js"></script>
  ...
</html>
```

That way the google analytics snippet could be managed with a dependency manager like bower for example, and the google user-id would be the only part of the code that would be actually variable.

So how would I use requirejs to modularize this type of snippet (regardless of whether that would be the sensible thing to do here)?

Comment: i'm not sure it make sense to use require. I think concat its enough

Comment: @Evgeniy I know, it's more about wanting to understand how requirejs would work with a snippet like this. I know it might be a bad example.

Comment: so, in your case require js may be used as Factory, very roughly,  module that returns new 'instance' of analytics code. So its just accept param with id and run immediate invoking function. If you are intrested in, i can post some code

Comment: @Evgeniy Yeah I would be interested in that, that's exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Require like this:

In a single file:

```
// the `configuration` module:
define('configuration', function(){
  return {
    googleId: 'UA-XXXXX-X'
  }
});

// the analytics module
define('analytics', ['configuration'], function(googleId){
    var anID = googleId;

    (function(anID){
        /* google analytics code here */
    }()); 
});

// initialization of it all    
require(['analytics']);
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the example! I'd seen this: http://www.ringabell.org/en/un-simple-guide-pour-debuter-avec-requirejs/, but your example is even simpler. It'll help me get started, thanks again!

Comment: I've tried your example, but it returns an error: `Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (conf)`

Comment: my bad, removed conf param from configuration callback

Comment: Hmm, it's still returning the same error, see this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HplEs

Comment: Shouldn't the function definitions be the other way around?

Comment: Oh, if you use multi define in one file, you have to define module name manually, like this: define('configuration', [] , function(){...})

Comment: Do my proposed changes make sense, or could you improve on them?

Comment: absolutely, nothing to add)